# how can I generate an unique id for a string. in python

Tags: python, django

how can I generate an unique ID for a string, which means only that string has a that id and if we try to put another string in that function it does not match.

Comment: When you say "unique id for a string", do you mean that you have a string and you need to associate an id with it? Or do you mean you want to generate a unique id that is a string of characters?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am looking for associate a string with an unique id

Comment: Maybe you need to hash the string then. Without more details we can only guess what will help solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for [uuid](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html).

Or maybe you need [a hashing function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) such as md5 or sha1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html)

import uuid

uuid.uuid1()